# Is there a solution possible for the following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to solve the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a(1+x^{m})^{\frac{2}{m}}}x\,{\rm d}x$$

where $a$ is real number but is not equal to $0$ and $m>2$. Any help or upper/lower bounds on this integral will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I've corrected and revised my answer. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Using CAS like Mathematica and MellinTransform can be solve it for `m` even integers and $a>0$.

$$\int_0^{\infty } \exp \left(-a \left(1+x^m\right)^{2/m}\right) \, dx=\mathcal{M}_a\left[\int_0^{\infty } \exp \left(-a
   \left(1+x^m\right)^{2/m}\right) \, dx\right](s)=\int_0^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_a\left[\exp \left(-a \left(1+x^m\right)^{2/m}\right)\right](s) \,
   dx=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty } \left(1+x^m\right)^{-\frac{2 s}{m}} \Gamma (s) \,
   dx\right](a)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right) \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left(\frac{-1+2 s}{m}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{2 s}{m}\right)}\right](a)$$
for `m=3` and odd `m` Mathematica can't inverse Mellin transform.

for `m=4`

$$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (-1+2 s)\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\right](a)=\frac{2^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{a} K_{\frac{3}{4}}(a) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

where $K_{\frac{3}{4}}(a)$ is  modified Bessel function of the second kind.

for `m=6`

$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right) \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6} (-1+2 s)\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{s}{3}\right)}\right](a)=\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right) \left(\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2};-\frac{a^3}{27}\right)}{\sqrt{a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}-\frac{2 a \sqrt{\pi } \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{a^3}{27}\right)}{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}+\frac{2 a^2 \pi  \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{4}{3},\frac{11}{6};-\frac{a^3}{27}\right)}{9 \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{11}{6}\right)}\right)$

where $\, _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2};-\frac{a^3}{27}\right)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.